# Oracle TO_DATE NOT throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I just spotted curious behaviour of oracle [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions191.htm) function when used with [format_mask](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) parameter.

Basically, what I see is that in one case it ignores given format mask, and parses input with its own mask, and in other cases it throws an exception.

**Example I** expected behaviour - error thrown:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18-02-2016', 'DD/MON/YYYY') FROM dual
```

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

**Example II** unexpected behaviour - date parsed:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18-feb-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual
```

> February, 18 2016 00:00:00

I cannot see any remark of this in docs, so I am wondering if this incostincency is by design or is it bug or maybe I am not understanding something correct?

**Edit:**
Looking at answers I can agree that it is most probably by design. But what is done here looks dangerously "automagical" to me.

What if format will be interpreted (guessed by oracle) incorrectly? Is there any documentation on what is exactly happening here, so I can be sure that it is safe?

My question would be then - can I turn it off? Is my only option validating format on my own?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of running the snippets and editing the question to include actual output. I think it could relevant that you get "ORA-01843: not a valid month" and not "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" or something else.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the table here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#g195479

It is part of the String-To-Date Conversion Rules section of the Datetime format model. In the case of `MM` if there is no match, it attempts for `MON` and `MONTH`. Similarly if you specify `MON` and it does not find that, it attempts `MONTH`. If you specify `MONTH` and it cannot find that, it attempts `MON`, but it will never attempt `MM` on anything except `MM`.

In response to the question: `Can I turn it off?` The answer is, Yes.

You can do that by specifying `FX` as part of your formatting.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18/february/2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;
```

Now returns:

> [Error] Execution (4: 16): ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was
>   found where a numeric was expected

Whereas the following:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18/02/2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;
```

Returns the expected:

> 2/18/2016

Note that when specifying `FX` you **MUST** use the proper separators otherwise it will error.

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank You. Also, answer was on the page I linked in my question. o.O I really should have read that to the end.

Comment: No worries, it's a rather small section at the end of an otherwise large document. =)

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. Oracle tries to find deterministic date representation in the string even if does not comply with the defined mask. It throws the error only it doesn't find deterministic date or some required component of the date is missing or not resolved.

Comment: What exactly is this `deterministic date representation` and how it works? Where can I find description of it? And more important - how can I turn it off?
Also, if You consider my example, You can see that in both cases Oracle have exactly the same information to recognize real format and in both cases it cloud do it properly.

Comment: You turn it off when you specify exact mask: 'FX<mask>'. I was actually work with the determinism because `TO_DATE('2016111', 'YYYYMMDD')` is not deterministic i could be 2016-11-01 or 2016-01-11 and Oracle prefers the first element therefore it's 2016-11-01.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `02` could mean date/month/year anything, but `feb` would only mean one thing, a `month`.
Also I crosschecked the same in `11g` and got the same output as you got in `12c`. So it **has** to be by oracle design.

Comment: Yeah but `SELECT TO_DATE('feb-08-2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual` fails, right? I will update my question with to be more specific.

Comment: This gave error, but `SELECT TO_DATE('feb-08-2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM dual;` didn't. So has to be by design

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable Oracle's attempt to be helpful and interpret things that don't exactly match, you can use [the FX format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216):

> **FX**
>   Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and datetime format model of a TO_DATE function:
>
> - Punctuation and quoted text in the character argument must exactly match (except for case) the corresponding parts of the format model.
> - The character argument cannot have extra blanks. Without FX, Oracle ignores extra blanks.
> - Numeric data in the character argument must have the same number of digits as the corresponding element in the format model. Without FX, numbers in the character argument can omit leading zeros.
> - When FX is enabled, you can disable this check for leading zeros by using the FM modifier as well.

So your example would error with:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18-feb-2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

That will also require the delimiters to match exactly:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18-02-2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

If you get it right then it's OK:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18/02/2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;
SELECT TO_DATE('18-feb-2016', 'FXDD-MON-YYYY') FROM dual;
```

It doesn't complain about the different case in the second example. But it will complain if you omit leading zeros;

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18/2/2016', 'FXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;

SQL Error: ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item
```

... unless you *also* include the FM modifier:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('18/2/2016', 'FMFXDD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;
```